# Which .scss file should I make site updates on?

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-4

As you can tell by this question I'm still learning SASS and Bootstrap 4. With BS4 I've had to setup some .scss partial files and then import them into my site.scss file. In order to make changes to Bootstrap I made changes in my _my-theme.scss file. My question is when I want to make simple CSS changes, not dealing with BS, is it best to put them directly in the site.scsss file or should I put them in the _my-theme file?

Ex: if I just want to make a page-title class I see that it will work if I put it in either my site.scss file or in the _my-theme.scss file but which one is best practice and is there a reason why?

I know I need to only have the class in one or the other file, I just don't know which one I should be putting it in?

Here is my site.scss:

```
@import "scss/_custom-variables.scss";
@import "bootstrap/bootstrap.scss";
@import "scss/_my-theme.scss";


.page-title {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Here is an example of _my-theme.scss:

```
body {
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

/* Set padding to keep content from hitting the edges */
.body-content {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

.page-title {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: shouldn't you use the `container` class instead of your custom body-content rule ?

Comment: Probably, I just copied that from the site.css that gets auto created with a new MVC project and it uses Bootstrap 3. Again, still learning Bootstrap 4 and SASS.

Answer (score 1):

I am learning too, but from my experience you should wrap in a container instead of using css padding.

When you `@import` stuff in sass, you should avoid writing the file extension(`.scss` is not needed) and the underscore for partials too.

Answer (score 1):

In my project SCSS folder I put **bootstrap** in a separated folder that I will never touch for changes, because if Bootstrap updates I can safely update there too. The **core** folder is from my theme, if I change something there it's just for theme purposes, thinking that I can use this folder in another project, so it has to be very generic. At the **project** folder I put custom classes, overriding of **core** or **bootstrap** styles, project colors, project mixins. Then I have **vendors** folder that are exclusively from 3rd party libraries, also never touching, just for consulting, if I have to override I am gonna do that at **project** folder.

[image: SCSS folders]

My project/project.scss content:

```
// Custom styles
@import "custom";

// Mixins
@import "mixins";

// New colors
@import "colors";

// New styles
@import "override";
```

My project/_colors.scss content:

```
// Colors
.default-grey {
    color: #333;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-color: #ddd;
}
```

Then the main.scss import everything:

```
// Variables
@import "variables";

// Import Bootstrap source files
@import "bootstrap/bootstrap";

// Import core styles
@import "core/core";

// Import vendors styles
@import "vendors/vendors";

// Import project scss files
@import "project/project";
```